# Get Firestore documents in NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next.js13

I am new to React/NextJS, I am trying to get a list of documents from a Firestore Collection, using NextJS 13 in a SSR Page so I can list them below.

I can get the documents from within my function. However, how can I get them into the page so I can list them out?

My code:

```
import { FIREBASE_FIRESTORE } from "../../configuration/firebase";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

async function getCustomers() {
  const customers = await getDocs(collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "customer"));

  // I CAN GET DOCUMENTS HERE
  const data = customers.docs.map((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
}

export default async function CustomersPage() {
  const customers = getCustomers();
  // BUT HOW DO I GET THEM HERE???

  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: This should work just like any other API call that you might make in a react component.  Minimally, a hook should be what you want.  I bet there are many many examples out there. Did you try anything?

Comment: @DougStevenson This is a server side rendered page so using a hook is not an option.

Comment: You're supposed to use [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't return my customers within the function. What a ****

```
async function getCustomers() {
  const customers = await getDocs(collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "customer"));
  return customers;
}
```